# DropDownList selecting incorrect value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a DropDownList where I want to select an ID and its name twice, put that into a `DataSet` and bind to a `DropDownList`.  The below code is my Data Binding.

```
using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
{
    string selectQuery1 = "SELECT [profileID], [profileName], [positionID], [positionName] from vw_profile WHERE memberID=@memberID";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(selectQuery1, conn1);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberID);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conn1.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    conn1.Close();

    chooseProfile.DataSource = ds;
    chooseProfile.DataTextField = "profileName";
    chooseProfile.DataValueField = "profileID";
    chooseProfile.DataBind();

    choosePosition.DataSource = ds;
    choosePosition.DataTextField = "positionName";
    choosePosition.DataValueField = "positionID";
    choosePosition.DataBind();
}
```

On my ASP.NET page, when the user hits Submit, it is meant to grab the values and insert into a table.

```
protected void submitReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM vw_profile";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader viewReader;
        viewReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (viewReader.Read())
        {
            var memberID = (string)viewReader["memberID"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                string selectQuery1 = "SELECT * from vw_profile WHERE memberID=@memberID";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(selectQuery1, conn);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberID);
                conn1.Open();
                int submitProfileID = Convert.ToInt32(chooseProfile.SelectedItem.Value);
                int submitPositionID = Convert.ToInt32(choosePosition.SelectedItem.Value);
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
                string date = dateTime.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];
                int reportNum;
                reportNum = Convert.ToInt32(viewReader["reportNumber"]);
                reportNum++;
                string reportTitle = "#" + reportNum + " - " + date;

                SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
                conn2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sfgs_reports(profileID,memberID,positionID,reportTitle,reportContent,reportDateStamp,reportNumber) values (@profileID,@memberID,@positionID,@reportTitle,@content,@datestamp,@reportNumber)", conn2);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", reportContent.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberID);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profileID", submitProfileID);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positionID", submitPositionID);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportTitle", reportTitle);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datestamp", dateTime);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportNumber", reportNum);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn2.Close();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Now what happens when someone submits is that instead of grabbing the `Value` from the one I select, it is grabbing the Default value, as in the one displayed in the `DropDownList` by default.  Can anyone see anything wrong in this code that could be causing this?

Edit to show updated submitReport_Click method:

```
protected void submitReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM vw_profile WHERE profileName=@currentUser";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", User.Identity.Name);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader viewReader;
        viewReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (viewReader.Read())
        {
            var memberID = (string)viewReader["memberID"].ToString();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    string selectQuery1 = "SELECT [profileID], [profileName], [positionID], [positionName] from vw_profile WHERE memberID=@memberID";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(selectQuery1, conn1);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberID);

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    conn1.Open();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    conn1.Close();

                    chooseProfile.DataSource = ds;
                    chooseProfile.DataTextField = "profileName";
                    chooseProfile.DataValueField = "profileID";
                    chooseProfile.DataBind();

                    choosePosition.DataSource = ds;
                    choosePosition.DataTextField = "positionName";
                    choosePosition.DataValueField = "positionID";
                    choosePosition.DataBind();
                }
            }

            using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string selectQuery1 = "SELECT * from vw_profile WHERE memberID=@memberID";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(selectQuery1, conn);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberID);
                conn1.Open();
                int submitProfileID = Convert.ToInt32(chooseProfile.SelectedItem.Value);
                int submitPositionID = Convert.ToInt32(choosePosition.SelectedItem.Value);
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
                string date = dateTime.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];  
                int reportNum = 1;
                string reportTitle = "#" + reportNum + " - " + date;

                SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
                conn2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sfgs_reports(profileID,memberID,positionID,reportTitle,reportContent,reportDateStamp,reportNumber) values (@profileID,@memberID,@positionID,@reportTitle,@content,@datestamp,@reportNumber)", conn2);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", reportContent.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberID);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profileID", submitProfileID);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positionID", submitPositionID);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportTitle", reportTitle);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datestamp", dateTime);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportNumber", reportNum);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn2.Close();

                Page.Response.Redirect("default.aspx?ResponseCode=3", false);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: on which even u r binding your dropdown?

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what you mean.  The top box of code is in my Page_Load and then I have a submit button click method to grab that value and insert it, and other information, into a table.

Comment: what is chooseProfile ? dropdown list ?

Comment: @mck Yes, it is a `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said your DropDown Binding code is in Page Load Event...put your code in this block i m sure it will work..

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
{
    string selectQuery1 = "SELECT [profileID], [profileName], [positionID], [positionName] from vw_profile WHERE memberID=@memberID";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(selectQuery1, conn1);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", memberID);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conn1.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    conn1.Close();

    chooseProfile.DataSource = ds;
    chooseProfile.DataTextField = "profileName";
    chooseProfile.DataValueField = "profileID";
    chooseProfile.DataBind();

    choosePosition.DataSource = ds;
    choosePosition.DataTextField = "positionName";
    choosePosition.DataValueField = "positionID";
    choosePosition.DataBind();
}
}
```

Because When you click a button `POSTBACK` occurs in which  first `pageload` event runs after that your `button click` event runs. Since your `Page Load`event runs before your `Button Click` your  `DropDownList` Binded Again Set to its Default Value.So before Binding dropdown check that it should not be a PostBack Call.For This i use Page.IsPostBack which weathere its PostBack Call OR normal call.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying this now.

Comment: Hmm, still not working.  Could you tell me if I have modified my `SubmitReport_Click` method correctly?  I updated my Question.

Comment: @Trido put you page load dropdownlist control on that block not put that block in button click....your button click is right put your drop down binding code that is on pageload event in that if block...

Answer (score 1):

try to put the code something like this:

if(!IsPostBack)
{
dropdownlistname.items.clear();
do the things to bind the value
}